# Generating a dynamic JSON object

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

(I hope I can explain this problem properly... have a feeling I might be crucified...)

I have a dynamically generated HTML form filled with select lists which then get saved to the db using AJAX.

The select lists are named like this:

```
<select id="slFieldName1"><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option></select>

<select id="slFieldName2"><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option></select>
```

etc.

`FieldName1`, `FieldName2`, etc, are the actual column names on the database table - I am using reflection to get and set values.

Here is the process:

Client side:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
    var sData = {
        FieldName1: $('#slFieldName1').val(),
        FieldName2: $('#slFieldName2').val()
    };

    ProjectName.AJAXService.Save(JSON.stringify(sData), function (result) {
        // etc
    });
});
```

Server side:

```
public class SurveyData
{
    public string FieldName1 { get; set; }
    public string FieldName1 { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod(true)]
public bool SaveCSSurvey(string sDataJson)
{
    SurveyData sData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SurveyData>(sDataJson);

    List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>(); // this will be populated with the field names

    foreach (var fieldName in fieldNames)
    {
        s.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).SetValue(s,
            ((string)sData.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(sData)));
    }
}
```

My question:

How do I dynamically generate the JSON object that I want to pass to the AJAX service? Ie. instead of this:

```
var sData = {
    FieldName1: $('#slFieldName1').val(),
    FieldName2: $('#slFieldName2').val()
};
```

...I need to have some kind of JavaScript collection with all the field names, and have this object created by iterating the field names.

**Edit:** crux of the issue is creating this JSON object. Even if I just iterate through each select list using jQuery, and then get the field name by pruning its 'id' attribute, how would I then create the JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ES5 you can only do this with simple assignment for example in an iteration (versus as an assignment as part of the literal)

```
var sData = {}
fieldNames = ["FieldName1","FieldName2"]
fieldNames.forEach(function(fieldName) {
  sData[fieldName] = $('#sl'+fieldName).val()
})
```

In ES6 you could use a more concise way, but this does not support an iteration - just positively setting all field names/values

```
var sData =  {
   [fieldName] = ...

}
```

Comment: Looks promising - will try and bbiab. Thanks a lot.

Comment: slightly updated  and added an iteration driven by the field names

Answer (score 1):

If all you are wanting to do is submit the form you can submit it as form encoded data and use `serialize()`. Assumes using proper `name` attribute as required by forms.

```
$.post(url, $('#formId').serialize(), function(resp){
    // do something with response
});
```

If you really need that object as shown you can loop over each input and map it's name to object

```
var formData ={};

$('#formId :input').each(function(){
   formData[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically generate JSON Object from fields. I think the following example is what you looking for.

**Output :**

```
Object {FieldName1: "A", FieldName2: "A"}
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
    var sData = {};
  
    $('select[id^="slFieldName"]').each(function(){
         var attribute_name = $(this).attr('id').replace('sl',''); //Removing string 'sl'
         sData [attribute_name] = $(this).val();
    });
  
    console.log(sData); //Object {FieldName1: "A", FieldName2: "A"}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="slFieldName1"><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option></select>
<select id="slFieldName2"><option value="A">A</option><option value="B">B</option></select>

<button id='btnSave'>Save</button>
```